# How to get to the device registration page of cumulocity?

Tags: cumulocity

How to get to the device registration page of cumulocity?

I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi with Cumulocity.I followed all the steps from the following link < https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/devices/raspberry-pi/ >.I got stuck in the step where it suggests to register the device.

I do not find the registration page.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in devicemanagement application it is the first menu item on the left.

Answer (score 1):

When you log in to Cumulocity, chances are you are looking at the Administrator page. Up in the top right of the screen you'll see an icon with 9 dots next to your user name. Click that and then select "Device Management". This will bring you to the screen that has the device registration and other relevant links in the left nav menu.